# Geometry Nodes, how do I keep the particles from sliding with the edited mesh

Tags: particles, procedural, geometry-nodes

I want to set up a procedural landscape where the tree distribution is based on the location of the mesh sort of like how I have the displacement set up. However, when I move the mesh the X and Y locations of the points stay the same while the Z location slides up and down with the displacement.
Here is a video of the issue. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1X6YfJi2UtXq04B0zH2mIdU1a_L9-du6h/view?usp=sharing

---

This is what was in the Noise Texture 1 node group.
[image]

Comment: Looks more like an ID issue ... use blender 3 with fields ... it might solves your issue.

Comment: What do you mean by blender 3 and fields?

Comment: @HankTheTank: He means Blender 3.0 - which is still under development. With fields i think he means geometry nodes fields - which is the new great feature for Blender - and which has got now a new design and working since 3.0a. In 2.9 it had similar but also other nodes.

Comment: I probably misunderstood your Q ... Do you want to keep points stay on global X, Y while plane is moving? I thought you are refering to two glitching points ... Sorry

Comment: You're fine. and yes I'm trying to make a procedural landscape where the trees stay where they are relative to the global coordinates and don't move with the translated mesh

Comment: Sorry I didnt notice your comment ... using phrase "@nickname" in text sends automatically notification ... @Chris can you handle this Q? I'm out of thing about some inteligent idea with GN. Thanks

Comment: @vklidu: I like your answer and I think it is good. I would have made it similar. Maybe raycast node would be worth a try too 

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thank you so much for all the help. While I didn't use your exact method, it definitely helped me figure out the issue. I ended up branching out the geometry where I wanted the points to be distributed and then added a subdivide node to control the density. Then I converted vertices to points and reset the z location to 0. Then I randomized the translation on the xy axis using the noise texture. Finally, I used the original displacement node to return the points to the surface of the mesh.

Node Tree
[image]

Node Group
[image]

Comment: Great you found solution ... btw what is inside node group? Just Noise texture? I tried to recreate your node tree to learn from you, but my result is just flat plane with points. Can you extend your A? Thank you :)

Comment: The Node group is just the same noise texture setup I used for the original displacement. I grouped them so I wouldn't have to repeat any adjustments I made for the geometry displacement with the point displacement. The reason I replaced all the z coordinates of the points with 0 and then translated them up using the same noise texture was to keep all the points on the surface after I randomized the X and Y coordinates. Otherwise, the points would maintain their original z coordinate with the randomized X and Y coordinates which would place them most likely above or below the surface.

Comment: I'm not sure if I explained that very well so if you don't understand just let me know and I can share the blend file.

Comment: Multiply in Group was missing ... now I got the result :)

Comment: Finally I had a time to check your flow ... great solution thanks :) ... few cosmetic touches https://imgur.com/2ezsthM

Answer (score 5):

It is working in some way (with some glitches on borders) ... but I can't say I really know what I did ... hopefully someone smarter will help you.

[image]

[image]

*Geometry nodes (fields version) Blender 3.1 (this blender is not recognised as a blend file, so I can attach file here to play with.*

Comment: so of course +1 from me and if hank the tank is not satisfied, maybe i think about another solution ;)

Comment: @Chris I m totally new to GN so I would be interested in your solution ;-) points edge glitch seems to be issue of Density that tries to reach value due changing appearance in motion.

Comment: no, you are not, Totally new cannot provide such a solution!!! ;) ok...i think about it....give me time ;)

Comment: @Chris Also points are limited to dummy object size, that can be any size, but  ...
 what could be unlimited version? ... BTW I'm just new fields gave me a chance since they are more familiar to me ... like material nodes ;-)

Comment: and fields are new for me and i am unfamiliar with it because i don't know material nodes too....;)

Comment: Thank you so much for all the help. While I didn't use your exact method, it definitely helped me figure out the issue. I ended up branching out the geometry where I wanted the points to be distributed and then added a subdivide node to control the density. Then I converted vertices to points and reset the z location to 0. Then I randomized the translation on the xy axis using the noise texture. Finally, I used the original displacement node to return the points to the surface of the mesh.